# MySQL procedure wont insert any data, but the query outside of it works

Tags: mysql

I have a query that **works outside of a stored procedure (populate dejan_output table)**, but inside it doesn't. Why?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `test_sp`()
BEGIN

    declare avg_all double;
    declare Zipcode text(10);
    declare from1, to1, from2, to2, from3, to3, from4, to4 int;
    declare Year smallint;
    
    #######################################################################  
    #create output table here
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dejan_output;
    CREATE TABLE dejan_output(
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Zipcode text(10),
        year smallint,
        month tinyint,
        RevenueIn1000USD decimal(15,4),
        calendarData tinyint,
        processed bit
    );
    
    #######################################################################  
    #insert into output table here
    insert into dejan_output(Zipcode, year, month, RevenueIn1000USD, processed)
    select f.Zipcode, year(ReportingMonth) year, month(ReportingMonth) month, round(sum(RevenueUSD) / 1000, 4) value, 0
    from monthly_performance_data f join
    (
        select Zipcode, year(ReportingMonth) year, count(distinct month(ReportingMonth)) count
        from monthly_performance_data
        group by Zipcode, year(ReportingMonth) 
    ) d on f.Zipcode = d.Zipcode and year(ReportingMonth) = d.year and d.count = 12
    group by f.Zipcode, year(ReportingMonth) , month(ReportingMonth)
    order by f.Zipcode, year(ReportingMonth) , month(ReportingMonth);
    
END
```

The table is created successfully but without any data. I am running it from MySQL Workbench 8.0.

Comment: Try insert into with handwritten values. Did you try your select query in single query page? Is it return rows?

Comment: sure it is working, that is why I've posted this question here because I can't see what is wrong

Comment: You use reserved words as columns names/aliases. This seems to be wrong - rename them, or at least quote them.

Comment: If the code works outside the SP then it will work inside the SP. Can you provide sample data that proves that it does not work in the SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was causing this but I still don't know why? Still, I will publish my solution so someone else can follow. Just remove any declarations:

```
declare avg_all double;
declare Zipcode text(10);
declare from1, to1, from2, to2, from3, to3, from4, to4 int;
declare Year smallint;
```

Because you can use

```
set @Zipcode = 'some value'
```

to set that variable.